# What have I done here?

Tags: knowledge, rebus

I have a bad habit of lurking around and answering other riddles without offering my own. So here is my first attempt the break the tradition, a simple rebus puzzle if you will. It just might be too easy.

[image]

Note:

> I had planned to post my puzzle towards the end of the year. Also the riddle won't be accepted unless you can find them all. :)

Hint 1:

> This puzzle is a hybrid one. Both a rebus and some knowledge needed. The theory is quite simple. Just read in between the lines.

Comment: Another hint will come tomorrow if nobody gets it. Also I would like a complete answer if possible rather than in fragments. Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is-

> Linkin park, this was found by @sedrick first

Title:

> what i've done, a song by linkin park.

Hidden clues:

> The wordings in the description may point towards some more LP song - 
> Breaking the habit (OP used break the tradition and bad habit)
>  Crawling (OP said lurking), 
> In the end and Waiting for the end ,(OP said towards the end),
>  The hint points towards the album - Hybrid theory, so remaining ones are probably from this album, 
> I am guessing it is- My December, (reading in between the given line -toward the end of the year.)

Comment: Oh wow this is pretty clever. Nice catch!

Comment: Almost there! You're one step closer to the end! Look carefully again!

Comment: "One step closer" is the title of one of their songs too xD

Comment: This is a clever puzzle. I've already given up, though.

Comment: ["gbjneqf gur raq bs gur lrne" ersreevat gb gurve fbat "va gur raq"? ] rot13

Comment: already added that @nikki .

Comment: You have almost got them all. Keep wracking your brain :)

Comment: Btw ,nice pun @jafe using yet another LP song in ur comment ;)

Comment: @jafe XD , I just noticed this. I intended to use it in the original question but I didn't want to put too many things in it.

Comment: @ShahriarMahmudSajid I'll help you out here, since you almost got it all. Read all the words carefully. Are you sure you aren't overlooking anything?

Comment: @ShahriarMahmudSajid The last part is a bit of a stretch. It wasn't intended. I will add a hint after some time.

Comment: rot13 [Vf gur zvffvat pyhr "svaq gurz nyy", ersreevat gb Cbxrzba?]

Comment: @PhilMJones nope. All the hidden messages are linked to the main rebus. I will add a hint tomorrow

Comment: @R.D rot13 [Gur evqqyr jba'g or npprcgrq vs lbhe nafjre vf VA CVRPRF?] perhaps?

Comment: @Wondercricket nope. I'll add the hint in a few hours

Comment: @ShahriarMahmudSajid No still incorrect. The hint only hints at the answer, not hide the answer in the hint. And I would like it if you edited your answer a bit to answer the entire riddle actually. Not just a continuation of someone else's answer

Comment: :D Good job! To anyone who hasn't listened to Linkin park yet, you might wanna give them a try

Answer (score 14):

Is it perhaps

> Linkin Park

Title:

> Linkin Park has a song named "What I've Done"

Comment: You are on the right track here. But there is more than meets the eye to this one :)

Comment: In hindsight, maybe I should not have used that title XD

Comment: Nah, I'm actually not that familiar with their songs, so I don't think it's a dead giveaway or anything. I just searched up Linkin' Park songs after solving the rebus to see if the title was somehow connected

Comment: Aah. Btw was the rebus too easy?

Comment: Hmm I'd say it's fine? Maybe the second picture because when I saw it, the first word that came into my mind was immediately park.

Comment: Hmm I see. Will keep it in mind next time

Comment: Love the puzzle though! Puzzles with more than one layer are always fun :)