# Do you all like rebus?

Tags: knowledge, rebus

Pretty easy puzzle, this is.  Yes, hmmm.

[image]

Comment: I noticed that the sentence is in yoda-speak so I’m expecting the rebus to be as well

Comment: @RohitJose Related, not everything is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the spirit of your [other recent rebus](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/70993)... I'm going to say

> Leave out all the rest
>
>  Bye = leave, the arrows point out, and then there's all the rest :)

Comment: Dang. No more LP references from now on lol. Good job